# Does clojure.data.zip.xml have a way to return a proper location for clojure.zip/append-node?

Tags: clojure

clojure.data.zip.xml has the (xml-> ...) function which finds data.
Is there a function to return a location (using similar to (xml-> semantics) so that I could use the location to append a node to the tree using the (zip/append-child ...) using the clojure.zip library?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

`xml->` returns a seq of zipper locs, each of which can be used with `append-child`:

```
;; using data.xml 0.0.7 and data.zip 0.1.1
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip]
         '[clojure.data.xml :as xml]
         '[clojure.data.zip.xml :as xz])

(-> (xz/xml-> (zip/xml-zip (xml/parse-str "<a><b>Foo</b><c>Bar</c></a>"))
              (xz/tag= :b))
    first
    (zip/append-child (xml/->Element :d {} "Quux"))
    zip/root
    xml/emit-str)
;= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><a><b>Foo<d>Quux</d></b><c>Bar</c></a>"
```

Comment: Thank you, Michał. Very good example. I missed the fact that we need to take the first element returned by xml->.